# Call ajax function while child browser window close

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using this code to update the database while the child browser window close

```
window.onbeforeunload  = check;
    function check(){

          var url = 'chat_update.php?chatId='+<?php echo $_GET['chatId'];?>;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url + Math.random(),false);
            xmlhttp.send();

            return false;
    }
```

it's working fine but check() function still calling when the child browser window refresh. Any solution to call the function only on child window close ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine if the window is getting closed or refreshed (see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), especially the **To Invoke** part). But from within your main window you could check, if the child window is closed, after the `onbeforeunload` event fired (I assume that you have a reference in your main window to your child window).

```
// in main windows js
child.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if(child.closed) {
            // Perform your ajax here
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: i put this in parent window , it only triggered once if we close the parent window. It needs to trigger the event on child window close. any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please note - `onbeforeunload` is not supported in Opera, try to use `onunload`.